# How to get a link with web scraping

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, last.fm

I would like to create a web scraping with some Python library (Beautiful Soup, for example) to collect the YouTube links on this page:

https://www.last.fm/tag/rock/tracks

Basically, I want to download the title of the song, the name of the artist and the link to Youtube. Can anyone help me with some code?

Comment: Scraping the Last.fm website is against the [Last.fm API ToS](https://www.last.fm/api/tos), which you agreed to if you've ever created a Last.fm API key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, provide some code to show what you have attempted.

I have expanded on Fabix answer. The following code gets the Youtube link, song name, and artist for all 20 pages on the source website.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

master_url = 'https://www.last.fm/tag/rock/tracks?page={}'

headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3"
}

for i in range(1,20):
    response = requests.get(master_url.format(i), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    chart_items = soup.find_all(class_='chartlist-row')

    for chart_item in chart_items:
        youtube_link = chart_item.find('a')['href']
        artist = chart_item.find('td', {'class':'chartlist-artist'}).find('a').text
        song_name = chart_item.find('td', {'class': 'chartlist-name'}).find('a').text
        print('{}, {}, {}'.format(song_name, artist, youtube_link))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.last.fm/tag/rock/tracks'

headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3"
}

links = []

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
soup.encode('utf-8')

urls = soup.find_all(class_ = 'chartlist-name')

for url in urls:
    relative_link = url.find('a')['href']
    link = 'https://www.last.fm/' + relative_link
    links.append(link)
print(links)
```

With the fuction `soup.find_all` you find all the tag with the class: "**chartlist-name**".

The `for` loop is used to remove the html tags and to append the links in the "**links**" list

Comment: Thanks Fabix. I have expanded your answer so that it gets the name, artist, and Youtube link for all 20 pages.